# Как подключится к heroku базе данных?

Tags: python, sql, heroku

Я хочу создать базу данных на heroku, но как потом подключиться к ней с помощью python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования PostgreSQL в качестве базы данных в приложениях Python вам понадобится пакет psycopg2.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Используйте этот пакет для подключения к *DATABASE_URL* в вашем коде:

```
import os
import psycopg2
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```

В официальной документации всё подробно расписано для различных ЯП:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python

Comment: День добрый. Хорошо бы основное из статьи перенести в ответ, у нас ответы-ссылки не приветствуются.

Comment: Пока не ознакомился с местными правилами, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ипользуйте:

```
import os, psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=NAME
host= HOST 
password=PASSWORD")
```

Все данные берутся из учётных данных на сайте Heroku в вашей базе данных

```
cur = conn.cursor() - Это команда создает переменную, которая позволяет управлять записью и чтением из базы

cur.execute() - для записи и создания новых таблиц
cur.fetchone() - для самого чтения. Дальше можно работать, как и с обычными данными на пк.
```

Перед закрытием необходмио ввести эту комануд:

```
conn.commit()
```

И дальше сами файлы закрытия:

```
cur.close()

conn.close()
```

Всё остальное описано в документации:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation